# Is there a way to retract a mistaken vote?

Tags: support, down-votes, voting, up-votes

I upvoted an answer too hastily. When I realized that the answer was wrong, I tried to cancel my upvote with a downvote. However, that simply replaced my upvote with a downvote (at a cost to the reputation of the answerer and myself). The answer, while wrong through its incompleteness, wasn't so bad as to warrant a downvote, in my view; it just didn't deserve an upvote in its present state. So, in particular, is there a way just to withdraw an upvote cast in error for an answer? More generally, is there a way to neutralize any of one's mistaken votes, within a reasonably short time, leaving no net effect on anyone's reputation?

If I may anticipate one type of answer to this question: the solution is not to vote in haste. This is a lesson I have already tried to learn.

Answer (score 6):

Click on the arrow again, it will retract the vote without incurring a downvote. Once five minutes pass, the vote is locked and an edit is needed to change or retract it.

Answer (score 4):

Just click the upvote button again to cancel it. (Or the downvote button, now that you've replaced your upvote with a downvote.)